# Passing multiple values to the form

Tags: python, django

I am getting this error: `'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_meta'` , when I am trying to pass an instance to the form.

Views looks like this:

```
def edit_post(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    image = PostImage.objects.filter(post__pk=post.pk)

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST, instance=post)
        form2 = ImageForm(request.POST, instance=image)

        try:
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                messages.success(request, 'Ok')
        
        except Exception as e:
            messages.warning(request, "No")
    
    else:
        form = PostForm(instance=post)
        form2 = ImageForm(instance=image)

    context = {
        'form':form,
        'post': post,
        'form2':form2
    }

    return render(request, "update.html", context)
```

I suppose the error has something to do with this line of code:

```
image = PostImage.objects.filter(post__pk=post.pk)
```

Previously it was `get` instead of `filter` , but it returns more than one value, so I had to change it.

I also tried to make a `for` loop:

```
for x in image:
  form2 = ImageForm(instance=x)
```

But it would display only one value.

models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = HTMLField()

class PostImage(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to = 'post')
```

view for creating a post:

```
def post(request):
    ImageFormSet = modelformset_factory(PostImage,
                                        form=ImageForm, extra=3)
 
    if request.method == 'POST':
    
        postForm = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        formset = ImageFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES,
                               queryset=PostImage.objects.none())
    
    
        if postForm.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
            post_form = postForm.save(commit=False)
            post_form.author = request.user
            post_form.save()
    
            for form in formset.cleaned_data:
                if form:
                    image = form['image']
                    photo = PostImage(post=post_form, image=image)
                    photo.save()
                    
            return redirect('detail', pk=post_form.pk)
        else:
            print(postForm.errors, formset.errors)
    else:
        postForm = PostForm()
        formset = ImageFormSet(queryset=PostImage.objects.none())
    return render(request, 'post_form.html',
                  {'postForm': postForm, 'formset': formset})
```

Comment: how did you create the post and its images?

Comment: @ha-neul I have added models to the post.

Comment: How did you create post do you have crest-post view?

Comment: @ha-neul Check out my view for creating a post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Inlineformset for this.

```
def edit_post(request,pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    ImageFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Post, PostImage, 
                                        fields=('image',), extra=4, max_num=4)
    
    if request.method == 'POST':

        postform = PostForm(request.POST, instance=post)
        formset = ImageFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance = post)

        if postform.is_valid():
             post = postform.save(commit=False)
             # other code
             post.save()
                    
             if formset.is_valid():
                 formset.save() 
           
             return redirect('detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        postform = PostForm(instance=post)
        formset = ImageFormSet(instance=post)
    return render(request, 'post_form.html',
                  {'postform': postform, 'formset': formset})
```

Comment: Ok it kinda works, but there's one problem. When I am saving changes, the images are duplicating, so every time I update the post it doubles the images (2 to 4, 4 to 8)

Comment: Thank you, it works now. I have got one more question, Is it possbile to change `extra` value in `modelformset_factory` directly from the form, when I am adding a post, so I don't have to set a fixed value?

Comment: so far I was not able to dynamically set extra value.

Comment: so the only way to upload an image if you went over the set value, is to do it via django admin?

Comment: extra means that you will add one more than current form. you can set Max_num = 20 for example, this means you can add maxium 20. Try adjust max_num.

Comment: yeah I know, I just wanted to display like one fileField and then if I need more, then I would change the extra value to the amount I need. It feels unnecessary to display like 10 file fields, If you are gonna need that many only once in a while.

Comment: Not really, max means the maximum you allow. If you set extra=1, then you will have one more form. Now somehow one post saved 10 images already, then it will not show additional form when you edit.